# Python PyPDF2 'PdfFileReader' object has no attribute 'scaleTo' error

Tags: python, pdf, visual-studio-code, pypdf

This is my first program so I imagine there are a lot of inefficiencies. First I created a GUI that works on a combined PDF. In attempting to convert the working code to a code that iterates through a directory of multiple single page PDF's, I get an error. On the "PageObj.scaleTo(11*72, 17*72)" line I get the error in the question title. A GUI takes the user inputs for the variables "x" (directory), "a" (paper size), and "s" (state). It is to resize the page to the selected size, merge with a template (not append but a single page "PDF sandwich" I have heard it described), then overwrite the existing file. This is to happen to every PDF in the specified directory. I have tried several version of defining my PageObj variable, but can't seem to get it right.

```
# Variables for User input values
x = values["-pdf_dir-"]
a = values["-paper_size-"]
s = values["-state-"]

# Location to find seal templates
state = f"G:/Drafting/Kain Mincey/Allen's seals/Correctly Sized/{a}/{s}.pdf"

Seal_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(state, "rb"), strict=False)
input_pdf = glob.glob(os.path.join(x, '*.pdf'))
output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
page_count = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(x), '*.pdf'))
i = 0

if a == "11x17":
    for file in input_pdf:
        sg.OneLineProgressMeter('My Meter', i, page_count, 'And now we Wait.....')
        PageObj = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(file, "rb"))
        PageObj.scaleTo(11*72, 17*72)
        PageObj.mergePage(Seal_pdf.getPage(0))
        output_pdf.addPage(PageObj)
        output_filename = f"{x[:-4]}"
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: `PdfFileReader` returns the whole file.  `scaleTo` applies to a page.  You have to fetch the page you want with `getPage`.

Comment: @Tim Roberts This may be another post needed as you answered where my problem was, but any chance you could guide me a little more advice on how to properly use the getPage on a directory please. I know there is a list created but can't seem to figure out how to indicate open the first file do ..... get second file do....etc. until all files have been modified. In a single PDF one would simply PageObj = "named PDF".getPage(i) with I being the variable in the for loop.

Comment: Right,  Why can't that work?  `PageObj = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(file, "rb")).getPage(0)`?  Do you have multiple pages in each PDF?

Comment: @TimRoberts completely my fault was using it wrong trying to use getPage(0) by it's self instead of just adding it to the end of the existing line. It did produce a new error, but was fixed by adding strict=False it.  `PageObj = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(file, "rb"), strict=False).getPage(0)` Thank you for the quick responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PdfFileReader returns the whole file. scaleTo applies to a page. You have to fetch the page you want with getPage. –Tim Roberts Mar 28 at 21:02